# Can't build PHP 7.1 on Mac OS X - error: typedef redefinition with different types ('long' vs 'long long')

Tags: php, macos, build

I'm trying to build a completely clean PHP 7.1 from [the official `php-src/PHP-7.1.0` branch on github](https://github.com/php/php-src/tree/PHP-7.1.0) with Xcode 8.2.1 on OS X 10.11.6, but I'm getting this error:

```
make distclean
./configure
...
gawk: fatal: cannot open file `date/*.h*' for reading (No such file or directory)
...
make                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   BR php-7.1 
/bin/sh /Users/myusername/Sites/php-src/libtool --silent --preserve-dup-deps --mode=compile gcc -Iext/date/lib -Iext/date/ -I/Users/myusername/Sites/php-src/ext/date/ -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/Users/myusername/Sites/php-src/include -I/Users/myusername/Sites/php-src/main -I/Users/myusername/Sites/php-src -I/Users/myusername/Sites/php-src/ext/date/lib -I/Users/myusername/Sites/php-src/ext/ereg/regex -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.12.sdk/usr/include/libxml2 -I/Users/myusername/Sites/php-src/ext/sqlite3/libsqlite -I/Users/myusername/Sites/php-src/TSRM -I/Users/myusername/Sites/php-src/Zend  -no-cpp-precomp  -I/usr/include -g -O2 -fvisibility=hidden  -c /Users/myusername/Sites/php-src/ext/date/php_date.c -o ext/date/php_date.lo 
In file included from /Users/myusername/Sites/php-src/ext/date/php_date.c:21:
In file included from /Users/myusername/Sites/php-src/main/php.h:35:
In file included from /Users/myusername/Sites/php-src/Zend/zend.h:31:
In file included from /Users/myusername/Sites/php-src/Zend/zend_types.h:27:
In file included from /Users/myusername/Sites/php-src/Zend/zend_portability.h:52:
In file included from /Users/myusername/Sites/php-src/Zend/../TSRM/TSRM.h:23:
/Users/myusername/Sites/php-src/main/php_stdint.h:172:14: error: typedef redefinition with different types ('long' vs 'long long')
typedef long int64_t;
             ^
/usr/include/sys/_types/_int64_t.h:30:20: note: previous definition is here
typedef long long               int64_t;
                                ^
In file included from /Users/myusername/Sites/php-src/ext/date/php_date.c:21:
In file included from /Users/myusername/Sites/php-src/main/php.h:35:
In file included from /Users/myusername/Sites/php-src/Zend/zend.h:31:
In file included from /Users/myusername/Sites/php-src/Zend/zend_types.h:27:
In file included from /Users/myusername/Sites/php-src/Zend/zend_portability.h:52:
In file included from /Users/myusername/Sites/php-src/Zend/../TSRM/TSRM.h:23:
/Users/myusername/Sites/php-src/main/php_stdint.h:198:23: error: typedef redefinition with different types ('unsigned long' vs 'unsigned long long')
typedef unsigned long uint64_t;
                      ^
/usr/include/_types/_uint64_t.h:31:28: note: previous definition is here
typedef unsigned long long uint64_t;
                           ^
```

That missing date header during configure doesn't look good, but I'm not clear whether this is a local config issue or a PHP source problem. Any ideas?

**Update** further to  l'L'l's suggestions, I had a go at building in other ways. Building from the tarball works, however, I'd prefer to build from git as I want to be able to submit a PR back to php-src and everything will track correctly if I do that. The git build steps are not very happy:

```
./genfiles
Zend/zend_language_parser.y:49.1-5: invalid directive: '%code'
Zend/zend_language_parser.y:49.7-14: syntax error, unexpected identifier
make: *** [Zend/zend_language_parser.c] Error 1
+ CLEANUP_FILES='   ext/pdo/pdo_sql_parser.c   ext/date/lib/parse_date.c   ext/standard/url_scanner_ex.c   ext/standard/var_unserializer.c '
+ for f in '$CLEANUP_FILES'
+ cp ext/pdo/pdo_sql_parser.c ext/pdo/pdo_sql_parser.c.orig
+ grep -v '#line ' ext/pdo/pdo_sql_parser.c.orig
+ for f in '$CLEANUP_FILES'
+ cp ext/date/lib/parse_date.c ext/date/lib/parse_date.c.orig
+ grep -v '#line ' ext/date/lib/parse_date.c.orig
+ for f in '$CLEANUP_FILES'
+ cp ext/standard/url_scanner_ex.c ext/standard/url_scanner_ex.c.orig
+ grep -v '#line ' ext/standard/url_scanner_ex.c.orig
+ for f in '$CLEANUP_FILES'
+ cp ext/standard/var_unserializer.c ext/standard/var_unserializer.c.orig
+ grep -v '#line ' ext/standard/var_unserializer.c.orig
```

That error seems to be non-fatal.

```
./buildconf
You should not run buildconf in a release package.
use buildconf --force to override this check.
```

This was a problem with the `PHP-7.1.0` branch - `master` doesn't show this error.

To make sure everything was completely clean, I trashed my clone and started again - and this time the redefinition error went away and my build is now working. Ultimately that answers my question - this appeared to be a local config issue, though I don't know exactly what.

Comment: any specific reason (just curious) why you would go the `build` route, as opposed to using `brew` ?

Comment: I'm working on a fix for an issue in PHP, so I need to be able to compile it. I also have it installed from homebrew, but that's a working build I don't need to touch.

Comment: ah ... makes sense. may you can brew with deep logging (not certain) and figure out how their build differs from yours.

Comment: I suspect homebrew adds lots of extra stuff to handle local config paths, extension packages and multi-version support - I don't need any of that, just need to build the core binary with no extras. OS X is a supported OS out of the box, so this should work - I just don't know whether it's a PHP bug or a local config issue, before I go reporting PHP bugs...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend trying the stable release version of **[`PHP 7.1.0`](http://php.net/downloads.php)**. Using unstable, alpha/beta/dev versions it's expected to run into some problems (the version you are trying to compile is technically the "unstable" 7.2.0). The stable version also has all the proper build scripts included, so it's very simple to get up and running.

```
$ curl --location --output php-7.1.0.tar.gz http://ca3.php.net/get/php-7.1.0.tar.gz/from/this/mirror
$ tar -xzvf php-7.1.0.tar.gz
$ cd php-7.1.0
$ ./configure
$ make
$ make test
```

**Test Result**:

```
=====================================================================
TEST RESULT SUMMARY
---------------------------------------------------------------------
Exts skipped    :   48
Exts tested     :   26
---------------------------------------------------------------------

Number of tests : 15222            10166
Tests skipped   :  5056 ( 33.2%) --------
Tests warned    :     1 (  0.0%) (  0.0%)
Tests failed    :     4 (  0.0%) (  0.0%)
Expected fail   :    35 (  0.2%) (  0.3%)
Tests passed    : 10126 ( 66.5%) ( 99.6%)
---------------------------------------------------------------------
Time taken      :  228 seconds
=====================================================================

PHP_VERSION : 7.1.0
ZEND_VERSION: 3.1.0-dev
PHP_OS      : Darwin - Darwin Orion.local 16.3.0 Darwin Kernel Version 16.3.0: 
Thu Nov 17 20:23:58 PST 2016; root:xnu-3789.31.2~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
```

If you would like to stick with the **[`git`](https://github.com/php/php-src/tree/PHP-7.1.0)** version the only difference in compiling would be in the need to generate the build scripts beforehand:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/php/php-src.git
$ cd php-src 
$ ./genfiles
$ ./buildconf
$ ./configure
$ make
$ make test 

=====================================================================
TEST RESULT SUMMARY
---------------------------------------------------------------------
Exts skipped    :   47
Exts tested     :   26
---------------------------------------------------------------------

Number of tests : 15223            10218
Tests skipped   :  5005 ( 32.9%) --------
Tests warned    :     1 (  0.0%) (  0.0%)
Tests failed    :     3 (  0.0%) (  0.0%)
Expected fail   :    36 (  0.2%) (  0.4%)
Tests passed    : 10178 ( 66.9%) ( 99.6%)
---------------------------------------------------------------------
Time taken      :  233 seconds
=====================================================================

PHP_VERSION : 7.2.0-dev
ZEND_VERSION: 3.2.0-dev
PHP_OS      : Darwin - Darwin Orion.local 16.3.0 Darwin Kernel Version 16.3.0: 
Thu Nov 17 20:23:58 PST 2016; root:xnu-3789.31.2~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
```

Comment: @Synchro: You're welcome! so this helped you or not? I'm guessing it did from your edit. If the original clone had already messed up during compilation I find it's always best to start fresh with a new one.

Comment: Once I figured out that the fatal-looking errors from genfiles and buildconf were not actually fatal, it built fine! Just about to push my first php-src PR...